# Nelson-Siegel-Svensson parameters provided by the Bundesbank

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, data, germany, yield-curve

I am a college student and I have recently learned about Nelson-Siegel-Svensson method which is used by the German Federal Bank to determine the yield curve. I have to generate yield curves of different shapes using historical data ($\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$, $\tau_1$ and $\tau_1$) which I am free to choose myself.

On the [website](https://www.bundesbank.de/dynamic/action/en/statistics/time-series-databases/time-series-databases/759784/759784?listId=www_skms_it03c) of the German Federal Bank I see the monthly and daily estimated parameters for the period from September 1972 until today. I have the formula but I am not sure which numbers to use. Could somebody please explain to me, whether the monthly estimated parameters are suitable to generate an yield curve for the next 10 years?

I am sorry if the question is too easy. I would be very grateful, if anyone could help me to understand which parameters I can use.

Comment: Love the profile pic. Please make the life of would be answerers easier by linking to the site with the estimated parameters.

Comment: Thank you:) here is the link: https://www.bundesbank.de/dynamic/action/en/statistics/time-series-databases/time-series-databases/759784/759784?listId=www_skms_it03c

Answer (score 3):

If anyone ever wonders the same, I´ve just tried weighting the monthly parameters and that leads to the correct interest rates :) you take 1 / 12 * ∑ (12 values of the respective parameter for the respective year). The answer was way easier than I thought :D